# Good book on characteristic functions that includes the CF-proof of the CLT

Tags: references, central-limit-theorem, characteristic-function

The title basically says it all. I would like to learn about CF in order to understand the proof of the CLT that makes use of CF. Ideally I would like to read a book that does not only give proves of the theorems and properties but also contains some text why these properties are also intuitively plausible. So I would be glad if you could recommend me a decent book for self-studying.

Comment: Which version of the CLT? Classical (iid)?

Comment: Yes, classical is fine!

Answer (score 0):

Many books on probability theory would do, but one book that seems to fit is  [Theory of Probability by Boris V. Gnedenko](https://www.betterworldbooks.com/product/detail/theory-of-probability-9789056995850) (sixth edition), which have an entire chapter dedicated to characteristic functions, and uses those to prove the CLT.